# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' and downloading sklearn would hang in terminal

Tags: python, scikit-learn, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I have searched for a solution to this problem, but none of them worked.
This is what I get in the terminal:

```
**Using cached scikit-learn-1.1.1.tar.gz (6.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error**
```

It would hang for a few minutes and print `error: subprocess-exited-with-error`. Wonder if this is because of pip3 or python's version but I have them up to date. And I am using M1 Mac.

```js
pip3 install scikit-learn                   
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.1.1.tar.gz (6.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [223 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools<60.0
        Using cached setuptools-59.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
        Using cached Cython-0.29.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (985 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.5.28-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
        Using cached scipy-1.8.1.tar.gz (38.2 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [191 lines of output]
            setup.py:486: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/vb/df8t2_dj7lj_hrnc9hbyv69w0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-1tg_c6wr'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
              warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
            setup.py:602: DeprecationWarning:
      
              `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
              of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
              Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
              It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
              For more details, see:
                https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      
      
              from numpy.distutils.core import setup
            Running from SciPy source directory.
            Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
            Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
            Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
            Processing scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx
            Processing scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx
            Processing scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx
            Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx
            Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
            Processing scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.pyx
            Processing scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_sqrtm_triu.pyx
            Processing scipy/linalg/_cythonized_array_utils.pyx
            ~ and more ~  (maximum txt is 30000 letters)
            Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/binom_ufunc.pyx
            Processing scipy/stats/_unuran/unuran_wrapper.pyx
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1469:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1469:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1469:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
            /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py:102: _ExperimentalProjectMetadata: Support for project metadata in `pyproject.toml` is still experimental and may be removed (or change) in future releases.
              warnings.warn(msg, _ExperimentalProjectMetadata)
            /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py:194: UserWarning: `install_requires` overwritten in `pyproject.toml` (dependencies)
              warnings.warn(msg)
            Cythonizing sources
            INFO: lapack_opt_info:
            INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
            INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
            INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
            INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
            INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
            INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: flame_info:
            INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: accelerate_info:
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_3_10_threads_info:
            INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
            INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
            INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_3_10_info:
            INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
            INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
            INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_threads_info:
            INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
            INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
            INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: atlas_info:
            INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
            INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
            INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: lapack_info:
            INFO:   libraries lapack not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
                Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
                Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
                numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
                the LAPACK environment variable.
              return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
            INFO: lapack_src_info:
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
                Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
                Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
                numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
                the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
              return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/var/folders/vb/df8t2_dj7lj_hrnc9hbyv69w0000gn/T/tmpdfnbfg85_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
                main()
              File "/var/folders/vb/df8t2_dj7lj_hrnc9hbyv69w0000gn/T/tmpdfnbfg85_in_process.py", line 345, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
              File "/var/folders/vb/df8t2_dj7lj_hrnc9hbyv69w0000gn/T/tmpdfnbfg85_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
                return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
              File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 188, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
                self.run_setup()
              File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 281, in run_setup
                super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
              File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
                exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
              File "setup.py", line 628, in <module>
                setup_package()
              File "setup.py", line 624, in setup_package
                setup(**metadata)
              File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
                config = configuration()
              File "setup.py", line 526, in configuration
                raise NotFoundError(msg)
            numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
            To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
            See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
            https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
      
      × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

~ 47s
❯ pip3 install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.23.0)
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.8.1.tar.gz (38.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [191 lines of output]
      setup.py:486: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/vb/df8t2_dj7lj_hrnc9hbyv69w0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-s_6p498y'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
      setup.py:602: DeprecationWarning:
      
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      
      
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
      Running from SciPy source directory.
      Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
      Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
      Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
      Processing scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx
      Processing scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx
      Processing scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx
      Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx
      Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
      ~ and more ~
      Processing scipy/stats/_sobol.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/nbinom_ufunc.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/hypergeom_ufunc.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/binom_ufunc.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_unuran/unuran_wrapper.pyx
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1469:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1469:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1469:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py:102: _ExperimentalProjectMetadata: Support for project metadata in `pyproject.toml` is still experimental and may be removed (or change) in future releases.
        warnings.warn(msg, _ExperimentalProjectMetadata)
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py:194: UserWarning: `install_requires` overwritten in `pyproject.toml` (dependencies)
        warnings.warn(msg)
      Cythonizing sources
      INFO: lapack_opt_info:
      INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
      INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
      INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
      INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: flame_info:
      INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: accelerate_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_info:
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_info:
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries lapack not found in ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO: lapack_src_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 188, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 281, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 628, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 624, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
          config = configuration()
        File "setup.py", line 526, in configuration
          raise NotFoundError(msg)
      numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
      To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
      See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
      https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Jupiter notebook does import `numpy`, `pandas` and `matplotlib`. Please help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: it is posted directly above `This error originates [...]` -> No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
      To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
      See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
      https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
      [end of output]

Comment: Thanks, but still not working after trying it. I see people having the same errors but not a single solution..hmm..

Comment: maybe it’s because of the m1 in the mac

Comment: Yeah perhaps, too bad :/

Comment: i think its better to ask this question on the github page of the package. i found something similar - maybe it helps: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13409

Comment: It worked @FabianClemenz thank you!! (Left a comment a few hours ago but is somehow deleted)

Comment: you could also upvote my comment :)

Comment: I would appreciate it if you leave an answer, so I can upvote your answer because you just  left a comment.

Comment: done that - maybe you could comment what exactly helped from this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found something similar here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13409 as mentioned in the comments

Comment: Jmos's comment in the link helped me out. I can't upvote this answer at the moment because I am fairly new, but I will when I have reputations enough to do that.